# How can I export an MS Outlook .pst file to Apple Mail?

Tags: email, ms-office

I want to export an MS Outlook .pst file to Apple Mail. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Do it via an IMAP server, which you can install on the Mac. I used `dovecot`, created an account on it, added that account to Outlook and just moved it all over. Then in Mail, I created the same account, and copied everything over.

I prefer this method because it completely preserves all the properties of each message, including attachments. Exporting and importing through another method (including Thunderbird) doesn't preserve everything properly.

Comment: thank for answer but now i use pop3 to get email

Comment: Irrelevant. You're setting up a mail server on your own computer for the purpose of transferring mail between Outlook and Mail.app. This has no bearing on your current email account.

Comment: +1 - This is reasonably simple to do and complete. It doesn't hurt that it's free too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Outlook2Mail](http://www.littlemachines.com/). It can export mails, contacts and calendar entries.

But there are a few caveats:

- 12,95USD
- Only U.S./English versions of Windows and Outlook are supported at this time. Little Machines does not guarantee the successful conversion of non-English characters, languages other than English and date formats outside of the United States.
- You need a computer which is still running Outlook to export. You can't just copy the PST to your Mac and convert it.

Comment: -1 - Limited and not free, just go the IMAP route.

Comment: slomojo, you are wrong to vote this down simply because it requires a commercial utility. People who develop commercial utilities need to make a living.